# modify script that uses Modulus to print alternate rows.?

Tags: php, post, rows, modulus, alternating

i think i maybe in over my head, but i'm trying to modify a forum script. specifically that part that posts a new topic and subsequent replies.

like typical forum scripts it prints alternating backgrounds for each post.

it use a modulus calculation to determine whether a post number is odd or even and thus prints the corresponding style.  so the new topic is the first post in the thread, say that's white, the next post(reply) is gray, the next is white and so on it alternates.

i want the first post to be white and all other posts there after to be gray.

this is a snippet of the code it uses to generate the post row tables.

function create_post_row($post_number, $elements)

// Generates the HTML code for a post row

{
      $this->print_mode ? $post_template = "post_row_print" : $post_template = "post_row" . ($post_number % 2 + 1);
      $this->post_rows .= insert_values($post_template, $elements);
   }

i don't know if there is another equation it can be changed to that would produce the desired result but i can't think of one.

so i'm thinking i need to isolate the first post into it's own row.

but i don't know how to do that. can't i add an "if first post then print this, if not print that" to the above code?

i'm sorry if this is too vague, i know without seeing the code and my ignorance may made it difficult to off much help.

EDIT: it seems the css approach doesn't work it. every time a new post is entered a new instance of the child class is issued, so it has nothing to count. if i try to wrap the whole thread within the class, it can't distinguish from all the other bits in the thread to count childs.

so i'm back to thinking i need to use a if/then statement or something, to output the first post in a thread to a separate table row.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you don't mind about (much) older browsers (actually IE is the main problem as others are most of the time always last-version), you better use [CSS `nth-child` property](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd) to perform that...

Comment: thank you:) i think that will work.

Comment: The key is : if that's about how things are displayed, first search for a CSS solution; And CSS3 has many solutions :-)

Comment: yes you're right. i thought about using css but since every odd or even post would be effected by the class assigned to it, i thought i guess i have to find a way to put it in a separate class, which meant coding in this case. but it turns out it WAS a style and not a coding issue. i didn't think to refresh myself on css instead of assuming the css classes had limited ability. in short, i wasn't thinking about it right. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that posts gets into some html structure. If you want to specify all of them grey and only first one white you can set some default value to with simple selector that sets all posts grey and then use pseudo selector [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child) to change background of first post using only CSS to white.

Comment: thanks to both of you for the help. i understand now i can do it with css. i didn't know there was a css class that can select within itself. so all i have to do is assign the child class to the post row, set it to one color and then select the first child in the parent class to another.   thanks you both very very much for the help.:)